TypeORM add foreign key references invalid table
I am using typeORM to create a database using the following code
@Entity('Perfiles')
export class Perfil {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

  @Column({
    length: 270,
  })
    denominacion: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Usuario, (usuario) => usuario.perfil)
    usuarios: Usuario[];

}

@Entity('Usuarios')
export class Usuario {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

  @Column({
    length: 270,
  })
    userName: string;

  @Column({
    length: 270,
  })
    password: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Perfil, (perfil) => perfil.usuarios)
    perfil: Perfil;

}


I did just as the documentation says this tipe of relation has to be done. Then, when trying to save a Usuario entity this is the query that typeORM makes
query failed: ALTER TABLE "Usuarios" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_a8b47b700e6d61ba5fae9519726" FOREIGN KEY ("perfilId") REFERENCES "IWS2.0_dev.dbo.Perfiles"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
error: QueryFailedError: Error: Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Executing in the msql management studio this is the error that i get
Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 11
Foreign key 'FK_a8b47b700e6d61ba5fae9519726' references invalid table 'IWS2.0_dev.dbo.Perfiles'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

This happens with any type of relation i try to make. When I execute the query given by typeORM but without the quotes in "IWS2.0_dev.dbo.Perfiles" works just fine
